Development in docker container using Visual Studio 2022 (Not Visual Code)
So at the moment, all the microservices I am working with have been containerised and in Docker desktop.
The current process is to have the containers running in Docker desktop, opening the project in Visual Code and running the application via docker compose. This way, I'm able to use the debug and develop within the dockerised application while still having all the other microservices in my Docker desktop running so that I can have a complete dev environment which simulates the live system.
Now, I want to use Visual Studio 2022 instead of Visual Code. The problem I'm having is when I try to set it all up, Visual Studio wants to create a completely new container and throws an error if I try to connect to an existing container. I've also tried the simple method of attaching to process, however, it complains about the code in IDE being different to the .DLL of the container image so I have to change the settings to allow the application to run even if the source code doesn't match (which shouldn't really be used in this instance).
How do I go about replicating the current process in Visual Code to Visual Studio?

It has it's benefits - I don't need to install multiple pieces of software as the dockerfile contains everything I need. Also, I don't need multiple instances of Visual Studio up and running and the company I am working for only provides laptops with 8GB RAM so it's too costly on performance to run more than 1 instance of visual studio. Also, I am using Linux containers, not Windows.

@Dai ...your point? I don't want to have multiple instances of VS up and running but I prefer VS over VSC and would prefer to develop in that environment

Sorry but you're mistaken. Visual Studio fully supports developing and debugging applications that are containerised with Docker, including Linux containers on Windows. Microsoft even confirms this.

I'm not disputing that, I'm saying that your post reads like you're wanting to run VS within the Container, especially this part: " able to use the dockerised application as a development environment"

Have you considered using the compose tools in Visual Studio? While it isn't the exact flow you describe it should be similar.
By default, when you open a compose project it will start all of the containers in the compose file. The ones connected to your .csproj's in the same solution (detected by having the Dockerfile and csproj in the same folder) get special handling so the service process can be started under the debugger when you F5 but the container gets reused across F5s to maximise performance.

I have already attempted this method but it still fails because docker-compose attempts to create a new container which has the same name as the one I am trying to connect to so it throws a conflict error.

Sorry if i was unclear, I am suggesting you do not start the containers yourself and let Visual Studio manage the container lifetime for you. In fast mode it should only be restarting the service processes in your containers you're debugging which seems to be a similar expereince to what you are pursuing.
